# Creating user in Active Directory with C# errors

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to create a user in a specific OU in my domain. Here's what I got

```
public static string ldapPath = "LDAP://OU=Domain Users,DC=contoso,DC=com";
public static string CreateUserAccount(string userName, string userPassword)
{
    DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("contoso.com");
    ldapConnection.Path = ldapPath;

    DirectoryEntry user = ldapConnection.Children.Add("CN=" + userName, "user");

    return user.Guid.ToString();
}
```

If I remove the OU=Domain Users, it works, and I receive a Guid. However I need these accounts in my OU. I copied the ldapPath from the OU itself in AD Users and Computers. I know it's correct.

The error I'm getting is

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005009): The specified directory object is not bound to a remote resource

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.FillCache(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeGuid()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Guid()
   at ADINtegrationTest.ActiveDirectory.CreateUserAccount(String userName, String userPassword) in D:\_data\ADINtegrationTest\ADINtegrationTest\ActiveDirectoryUtils.cs:line 21
   at ADINtegrationTest.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\_data\ADINtegrationTest\ADINtegrationTest\Form1.cs:line 32
```

I'm running this on a member Win2k8 server to the domain, logged in as domain administrator. I will eventually need to create it in an OU under another OU, but lets start with this one.

Thanks for the help!
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// create a user principal object
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx, "User1Acct", "pass@1w0rd01", true);

// assign some properties to the user principal
user.GivenName = "User";
user.Surname = "One";

// force the user to change password at next logon
user.ExpirePasswordNow();

// save the user to the directory
user.Save();
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: thanks, now having issue with creating within a specific OU, made new issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715265/creating-user-in-a-specific-ou-in-active-directory-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that allow you to create a user using `System.DirectoryServices` :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace Exemple_ADSI12_AddUser
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      /* Connection to Active Directory
       */
      DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.183.100:389/OU=SousMonou,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr", "jpb", "PWD);

      /* User creation
      */
      DirectoryEntry auser = deBase.Children.Add("cn=a User", "user");
      auser.CommitChanges();

      auser.Properties["samaccountname"].Value = "AUser";
      auser.Properties["givenName"].Value = "A";
      auser.Properties["sn"].Value = "User";
      auser.Properties["displayName"].Value = "AUser";
      auser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = "AUser@dom.fr";
      auser.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;
      auser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 544;

      auser.CommitChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

You can do without using user/password, but you need to create a DirectoryEntry on the nod where you want to create an object. You can replace `LDAP://192.168.183.100:389/OU=SousMonou,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr` in my sample by `LDAP://contoso.com/OU=Domain Users,DC=contoso,DC=com`