# PrincipalOperationException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80005009

Tags: c#, web-applications, active-directory, docker-compose, samba

I built my Active Directory (AD) with Samba in Docker.

I can create user with Active Directory Explorer but I realize there is no way to add password for it.

So I use the example from the link below to create AD user in C#.

[Creating user in Active Directory with C# errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8684059/)

This is my code:

username = "User1Acct", password = "pass@1w0rd01"

```
public void CreateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        // set up domain context
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(AdType, HostName, CnName, UserName, Password);

        // create a user principal object
        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx, username, password, true);

        // assign some properties to the user principal
        user.GivenName = "User";
        user.Surname = "One";

        // force the user to change password at next logon
        user.ExpirePasswordNow();

        // save the user to the directory
        user.Save();
    }
```

I tested my connection to AD with the code below and it returns user result, so there is nothing wrong with my PrincipalContext instance.

```
public ADUser GetUser(string username)
    {
        PrincipalContext entry = new PrincipalContext(AdType, HostName, CnName, UserName, Password);
        UserPrincipal uP = new UserPrincipal(entry)
        {
            SamAccountName = username
        };

        PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(uP);
        var principal = search.FindOne();

        if (principal == null)
            return null;

        return new ADUser
        {
            SamAccountName = principal.SamAccountName,
            UserPrincipalName = principal.UserPrincipalName,
            DisplayName = principal.DisplayName,
        };
    }
```

The problem is, it returns this exception when my breakpoint hits `user.Save();`
PrincipalOperationException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80005009

I tried to google and follow some suggestion like:

1. remove OU
2. use more secure password

But none of these works...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is this a web app or a common desktop app?

Comment: @vasily.sib it is a web app.

Comment: then look at [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bb668d3-2f12-4e21-a0e0-27b786f38865/active-directory-access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-when-i-invoke?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious). Maybe this is because of your AppPool runing under wrong identity?

Answer (score 0):

Does the account you're supplying to PrincipalContext (UserName and Password) have sufficient permissions to create users in the target container referenced by CnName?

0x80005009L is an Active Directory Service "Object Unbound" error [1]

And comments from user, JMayo, wrt. same error code [2]:

> This isn't telling me a whole lot except my gut feeling is that the executing code doesn't have the proper permissions to do what it wants to do.  This would make sense if you consider the fact that it works fine in your development environment, where you are probably running as Administrator, but your code is only running as NetworkService when deployed.
>
> If it is true that your problem is related to lack of permissions, then you can probably impersonate a user that does have access to AD.

1. [IIS Constants and Header Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms524825(v=vs.94))
2. [Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation?](https://forums.asp.net/t/1371511.aspx?+Exception+has+been+thrown+by+the+target+of+an+invocation+)

== Edit ==

Your second example, `GetUser`, works because the `UserName` and `Password` you supply to `PrincipalContext` have sufficient access to get/read the user details from the `CnName` container.

That doesn't mean that same account has sufficient access to add or modify users in the `CnName` container so, as you're seeing, it can still fail when calling `UserPrincipal.Save()`.